# uanble to get certain words form text file

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Hi I'm wanting to get certain words from a text file rather than all the words in the file.
Basically this text file has certain words I want to delete if they are used in a message.

Then I want to send these words in a new message:

How this is not working for me it's just sending all the words `${word}` in the text file.

Heres what I'm working with

```
const badwords = fs.readFileSync("./badwords.txt","utf8").toLowerCase().split("\r\n");
const blocked = badwords.filter(word => message.content.toLowerCase().includes(word)); 

//filter through badwords


blocked.filter(word => {
    if(message.content.includes(word)){
        message.delete()
        log_channel.send(`Message deleted because it contained the words ${word}`) 
    }
})
```

Return values from `badword.txt` `test1` and `test2`

Answer (score 3):

Your mistake comes from how you detect if `badwords` were found in [`message.content`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=content). `blocked` is *already* an array of found badwords (hence why they all return when you re-filter them with the *same* condition) , all you need to do is check if it has a [`length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) greater than 0. To send a list of the found badwords take the array and [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) it into a string

```js
const badwords = fs.readFileSync("./badwords.txt","utf8").toLowerCase().split("\r\n");
const blocked = badwords.filter(word => message.content.toLowerCase().includes(word)); 

if (blocked.length) {
   message.delete()
   log_channel.send(`Message deleted because it contained the words ${blocked.join(' ')}`)
}
```

Comment: Im my text file `badwords.txt` I have two words these are test and test2. When I try your code above and type test 2 for example it will return both words test and test2 opposed to just test2.

Comment: Could you include the return values of your variables in your question

Comment: I've added my values. The issue seems as if it's getting both values from the blockwords file opposed to just the value that was used. For example, if I use the word `test2` it will return the values `test test2` opposed to just `test2` It is as if it's looping over both words in the file.  But if I use the word `test` it will return the value `test`.

Comment: Hmm, Might have something to do with the fact that `test` is included in `test2`

Comment: `blocked.length` doesn't seem to work on linux? tried on windows and its working fine. Seems to be `.length`?

Comment: Operating system shouldn't have an effect on JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have next badwords.txt structure

```
...
bad1
bad2
bad3
...
```

You need to split them by new line

```
const badwords = fs.readFileSync("./badwords.txt","utf8").toLowerCase().split("\n");
```

Then you need to find all words in message and convert to array

```
const message = "String with-one bad1 word, bad2, bad1".match(/\b[\w\-]+\b/gi);
```

And then just filter message and return new message

```
const filteredMessage = message.filter(word => {
  if(badwords.includes(word)) {
    log_channel.send(`Message deleted because it contained the words ${word}`)
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}).join(' ');
```

Comment: What is `filteredMessage`?

Comment: filtered message is the message without bad words, while the message is the one with

Comment: 'filteredMessage' value is never read?

Comment: @Jake that means you never use the constant `filteredMessage`

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not understanding the breakdown of your code. If you can put it in a full block then I may be able to understand it. It's thr forth codeblock don't really understand.